# PHP-script: Write IP-Adress in mySQL-Database. Doing that twice is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I use a PHP-Script to submit my IPv4 Address to my own PowerDNS-Server using that link:

```
script.php?domain=test.dns.com&ipaddr=11.22.33.44&passwd=auth-phrase
```

Therefore I modified the link in a way that the IPv4 and IPv6 are being updated simultaneously. I modified the update script, but then only one version will be updated (IPv4):

```
script.php?domain=test.dns.com&ipaddr=11.22.33.44&passwd=auth-phrase&ip6addr=2001:0db8:1234:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000
```

Here is the script I'm using:

```
<?php

// DynDNS-Service für PowerDNS
// @date   06.09.2012

$dsn     = 'mysql:dbname=pdns;host=127.0.0.1'; // Datenbank DSN
$user    = 'pdns'; // Name der Datenbank
$pass    = 'password'; // Datenbank Passwort
 
// Auth-String der als GET-Parameter übermittelt werden muss
$auth    = 'auth-phrase';
 
// Für alle im Array enthaltenen Records dürfen Updates gefahren werden
$allowed = array('ip4.test.dns.tld');
 
$domain  = (isset($_GET['domain'])) ? $_GET['domain'] : null;
$ip      = (isset($_GET['ipaddr'])) ? $_GET['ipaddr'] : null;
$ip6     = (isset($_GET['ip6addr'])) ? $_GET['ip6addr'] : null;
$domain6 = 'ip6.test.dns.tld';
 
 
if ((empty($domain) || is_null($domain)) || (empty($ip6) || is_null($ip6))) {
    die('missing parameter');
    exit;
}
 
if (!in_array($domain, $allowed)) {
    die('forbidden domain name');
    exit;
}
 
if (!isset($_GET['passwd']) || $_GET['passwd'] != $auth) {
    die('authentification failed');
    exit;
}
 
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
 
// HERE THE PROBLEM STARTS
 
//IPv4 UPDATE
 
$check = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id FROM records WHERE name = :name AND type = :type');
$check->bindParam(':name', $domain);
$check->bindValue(':type', 'A');
$check->execute();
$result = $check->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
if (empty($result)) {
    die('record not found');
    exit;
} else {
    $update = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE records SET content = :content WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $update->bindParam(':content', $ip);
    $update->bindParam(':id', $result['id']);
 
    // if ($update->execute()) {
         // die('update successful (' . htmlentities($ip, ENT_QUOTES) . ')');
         // exit;
    // }
    // die('update returned false');
    // exit;
}
 
//IPv6 UPDATE
 
$check2 = $dbh->prepare('SELECT id FROM records WHERE name = :name AND type = :type');
$check2->bindParam2(':name', $domain6);
$check2->bindValue2(':type', 'AAAA');
$check2->execute2();
$result2 = $check2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
if (empty($result2)) {
    die('record not found');
    exit;
} else {
    $update2 = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE records SET content = :content WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $update2->bindParam2(':content', $ip6);
    $update2->bindParam2(':id',      $result2['id']);
    if ($update2->execute2()) {
          die('update successful (' . htmlentities($ip, ENT_QUOTES) . ')');
          exit;
    }
    die('update returned false');
    exit;
}
?>
```

I already removed the `die();` part in the first part of the code. I also tried to rename the variable of the second part (check -> check2). But it's still not working. What did I do wrong? Why isn't it possible to write two times in the mysql-database?

I receive a blank site without any errors. But still: The update didn't work. There is no new updated IPv6 entry in my database.

Comment: Note: The domain being used in the link is "ip4.test.dns.tld", not "test.dns.com".

Comment: You need to find errors. A blank page usually means your code crashed.

Comment: Thanks. The thing is: the first part works (IPv4 Update). What can't I use it two times?

Comment: See: [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: What are `bindParam2`, `bindValue2`, and `execute2`? The names of the methods are just `bindParam`, `bindValue`, and `execute`.

Comment: A blank page really doesn't help us diagnose the problem, that's basically zero information. PHP if configured correctly logs the issues it has. If you don't know where that log file is, or it's not capturing errors, have a look at what Paul suggested as this is a critical part of the diagnostic process.

Comment: why you write `bindParam2` or `execute2`?

Comment: It works if I use `bindParam` instead of `bindParam2`. THANKS!